# How many possible operations are there of arity n? (N-ary)

Tags: logic

Not sure about this one! Can someone please help? Thanks

Comment: I think you need to be more specific with your question.

Comment: @user66118 Do you know that the cardinality of $|B^A|$ of $B^A$ is $|B|^{|A|}$, where $|A|$ and $|B|$ denote the cardinalities of $A$ and $B$ respectively?

Comment: Given that this OP has requested his first question be deleted, it is fairly likely this is a current examination of some kind.

Comment: This question strongly resembles the other question of the same user. No complaint, just saying. In the context of standard logic , Git's comment is good. I actually wanted to say that but Im too late. :)

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @willjagy ur right....but i ask for help....not answers......one user gave me a hint and i knew i was on the right track. But seeing it is for evaluation i wouldn't want to cause problems for other students copying my work? I think thats pretty fair....

Comment: Oh, good.${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends on the size of the underlying set $A$. Let us assume $A$ is finite, with $m$ elements, where $m\ge 1$.

In how many ways can we construct a function $f$ from $A^n$ to $A$?

For **every** ordered $n$-tuple $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ of elements of $A$, we have $m$ choices for the value of $f$ at $(a_1,\dots, a_n)$. How many ordered $n$-tuples are there?

Comment: @andreniolas hmmmm i may have some notes on this. Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Look at the special cases $N = 0$, $N = 1$, $N = 2$ to get a feeling for the question.